# Lazy loading of UIViews with drawRect: drawing

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit, lazy-loading

I have a large UIScrollView and nearly 40 big (1000x700) UIViews to put on it. Each of those views has several subviews with custom drawing. How should i lazy load those big views?
I looked up several solutions for lazy loading, but all of them refer to UIImage loading, and they use posibility to load UIImage after UIView is placed. But in my situation even adding big UIView as a subview causes lag. Is there any way to make scroll fast and at the same time lazy load the contents?

Comment: Have you considered using something like Coco2D for that kind of job? http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a UITableView instead of UIScrollView, then have your custom views added by UITableViewDataSource [cellForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) and lazy loading will just happen naturally.

Comment: Will it be faster then with addSubview:? I am asking, because Lazy Loading is pretty easy to make, the only problem is adding subviews (which makes lag)

Comment: Yes I agreee, a tableView would take care of the lazy loading for you.

Comment: It doesn't help. it still has lag when new cell is being added

Comment: What all are you doing while adding a view? Are you doing one view per table cell?

Comment: well... one big view which has like 20 subviews

Comment: Are all of the subviews dynamically chosen? Are any of them the same across rows? Are you doing any IO or heavy computations in the process of adding these subviews?